# DVD Writer uneven burn

Tags: dvd-burning

I have a DVD Writer Sony 870s. It was working alright earlier, Now (may be after new motherboard) its not writing DVDs correctly. The problem is that after I burn a DVD the DVD surface is not burned consistently, I can see shaded rings, see the attached image for description.
[image]

Comment: And do your DVDs validate and read fine?

Comment: DVD writer software like powerISO, imgBurn reports thats DVD burned successfully but I am not able to ready it properly. I am creating windows dvd clone and its not booting..

Comment: Found! I need to write DVD at 16x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I Found the solution. I need to burn it at maximum speed (16x). Not sure whats the science behind it.